# Integer[] can not be converted to Serializable

Tags: arrays, serialization, integer

I am trying to pass `Integer[]` to a function that accepts `<T extends Serializable>`. I know `Integer` implements `Serializable`. Why can not I pass `Integer[]`? How to resolve this issue?

```
classPropsUpdater {
    public static <T extends Serializable> void updateProp(String propName, T value){
       //do something
   }
}
PropsUpdater.updateProp("PromName", new Integer[]{1,2,3});
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Is your title an error message? And if so, from what?

Comment: It is a compilation error message.

Comment: Your code states that every `T` must be `Serializable`, but not every `Serializable` is also a `T`. Imagine if `X` and `Y` both implemented `Serializable`, but were otherwise unrelated, you couldn't compile`X x = new Y();`

Comment: @TEK I can't make head or tail of that, and it doesn't have anything to do with the question.

Comment: @EJP Evidently I have completely misunderstood the question. Hence why I left it as a comment, rather than making myself look even more foolish by leaving an answer. :)

Comment: @TEK Couldn't you just delete it all?

Comment: @EJP When I see an answer. :)

Comment: @TEK Irrelevance is irrelevance whether or not the actual question gets answered. I am suspecting the OP has his own interface called `Serializable`.

Comment: @EJP this is `java.io.Serializable`

Comment: I think I am narrowing down on problem, the function takes `Serializable` and I am passing an array of `Serializable`. But still isn't array of `Serializable` also `Serializable`?

Comment: Yes, in fact so is an array of *non*-`Serializable`. See [JLS #10.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8).